# Asp.net MVC - Multi lingual site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

I am tasked with developing a multi lingual site using ASP.NET MVC. For static content i am ok to have resx files to allow better scalability. But the problem comes for user entered data. User1 fills up a customer data form and saves it using language1. Now User2 when views the data, the data entered by user1 in langauge1 should be shown in the language of User2's choice. Can somebody help with some idea here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an automatic language translation service such as [Google's Translate](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html). Using it as simple as sending a GET request to `https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de` (translates `hello world` from English to German) and parsing the resulting JSON.

As pointed out by @olivehour, Microsoft also offers a [similar service](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/).

Don't expect miracles though as far as the quality of the automatic language translation is concerned.

Comment: And in addition, you'd probably want to store the translated result (indexed by culture) once retrieve from Google Translate because it'd be pretty slow to translate it every time a request is made.

Comment: How should i get `Key` part?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user inputted data translated into other users languages, you should request them to input it in those other languages. Or get editors to do that for them, assuming you want some level of quality in the translations.